# Rewrite example.com/index.php/... to example.com/... using mod_rewrite and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am migrating my site from Wordpress to Jekyll and I would like to keep the URLs working. My idea was to use a .htaccess file for this and to place it in the root of the site. But unfortunately after trying several tutorials and generates it doesn't seem to work.

The old URLs have the following format

```
http://example.com/index.php/2016/05/07/title-of-the-blog-post/
```

The new URLs have this format:

```
http://example.com/2016/05/07/title-of-the-blog-post.html
```

Among others I've tried this example which looks good to me, but it actually casues all pages on my site to display an error message :)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php.*$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I think that should take all URLs that start with `example.com/index.php` and make them start with `example.com/`, but apparently that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect

- `http://example.com/index.php/2016/05/07/title-of-the-blog-post/`

to

- `http://example.com/2016/05/07/title-of-the-blog-post.html`

you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ http://example.com/$1.html [NE,L,R]
```

or alternatively you can use `mod_alias` like that:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/(.+)$ http://example.com/$1.html
```

Comment: That one was very close! I needed to add one extra slash to make it work. It seems so simple after I saw your example :). `RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)/$ http://example.com/$1.html [NE,L,R]`